# Unable to get Text from styled Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am unable to get Text from textarea because of some unknown reason, if I try simple textarea without using any javascript library, it is getting text. But when using any library, it shows undefined. Can somebody explain why?

Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>

 <div id="sample">
<!--  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
  //]]>
  </script> -->
     
   <h1>
    Testing page for Text Areas
  </h1>

  <textarea id="area2" style="width: 80%;">
</textarea><br />
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="submit_text2"> Submit Email </button>

<p id="demo">jkjnjk</p>
</div>
      
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("area2").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  console.log(x);
    alert(x);
}
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[Here, it is getting and showing text in Alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbbbH.png)

Now if I uncomment the script to enhance my textarea using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
  //]]>
  </script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>

 <div id="sample">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
    //]]>
  </script>
     
   <h1>
    Testing page for Text Areas
  </h1>

  <textarea id="area2" style="width: 80%;">
</textarea><br />
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="submit_text2"> Submit Email </button>

<p id="demo">jkjnjk</p>
</div>
      
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("area2").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  console.log(x);
    alert(x);
}
</script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

[It has gone blank now, (there is no problem with script, I have tried some other as well!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n64kn.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you are using "styled textarea" it just create something else on top of your textarea. You need to use `[nicInstance].getContent()`. You can read  [niceEditor's docs here](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/521/Javascript%20API)

In your case since you haven't saved your instance a variable, you should being able to use `nicEditors.findEditor('area2').getContent();`